# Can I put every language in a single map?

Tags: html, css, internationalization

I want to make a website for more then 1 language.
I don't want to use programs to do this or Google translate.
I think I will translate everything by hand.

Can I just make a map for every language and put every page on it but then translated? I have like 30 pages for 1 language (because it has a lot of articles on a page). So then I have 4x that pages (because I am going to use 4 languages).
So is it actually smart to do this or does it make the website slow or something like that?

I'm open to learn new stuff and try out other things then just make a map for every language.

Comment: Do you mean 'folder'?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Yes I ment folder, im not english sorry :)
I'll try my best to make a better question next time  that is more understandable.

Comment: I hope that there are still people who read this, but I actually have another question which i want answer on and want to go futher with my site. But i think its a bit cheaty to make another account for it.

Becuase my question was bad I am not allowed to ask more questions in 2 days. I'm a little sad about that. 
My other question is more about html/css. It's about something not overflowing what it should be, and wrong positioning in my dropdown menu. I can't find it anywhere so any way to still ask it? 

I hope someone understands me and let me ask the question.

thanks allready.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

these are the facts about that:

pros:

- you will be able to control the translation procces and avoid errors from the translation engines
- you will be able to add stuff depending on the language and change appearence, like adding extra stuff for speakers of certain languages

cons:

- will be time consuming
- you will need to organize your files to avoid screwing things up
- if your website is like a bloging one were you update often will be unpractical to tranlsate each post in each lenguage

what you can do is add links to change the different languages by linking to folders on your server that contain each lenguage files and move from there, and use technologies to achieve this. good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answers even though this is not a good post.

Comment: (cant edit so this has to come after that sentence)
I'm using it for just a simple visit page for a little company so people see what this company does. :)